# how to fix variable value always be null after next() method redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I try some with **vue-cli** 3 package.
It is **vue** version 2.6.10.
While i try use router beforeRoute to guard the route and while I login first time it work fined but when i delete cookie, route guard doesn't get value of cookie to pass to api at all, it always show null on header request.

Please check my code below.

I try **vuex** but no luck.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Login from './views/login/route'
import Dashboard from './views/dashboard/route'
import axios from '../lib/axios'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    ...Login,
    ...Dashboard
  ]
})

router.beforeEach( async (to, from, next) => {

  // validate route is auth
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth)){
      var cookie = $cookies.get('basic-app-token');
      if(cookie != null){
          console.log('before send', cookie);
          let res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/token/check',{
            headers: {
              Authorization: 'Bearer '+cookie
            }
          });
          console.log('after send', res.data);
          if(res.data.success){
              next()
          }else{
            next({name: 'login'})
          }
      }else{
        next({name: 'login'})
      }
  }else{
    next()
  }

})

export default router
```

result on request header always show "Authorization: Bearer null".

Comment: Try using Axios' Interceptors to set and send token.

Comment: could you show a simple tricky pls ?